# How to get only closed / not closed questions from the API?

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions, api

My question is quite simple: I want to get only questions which are closed from `/questions` of the API.

I've played around a bit with the filters, and I've come up with [something which gives](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!*7Pmg84vZ4DiDS2g1yshkLV6zTe8&site=stackoverflow&run=true) me some JSON like this for each question:

```
{
      "tags": [
        "c++",
        "opencl",
        "intel"
      ],
      "close_vote_count": 0,
      "title": "Weird OpenCL calls side effect on C++ for loop performance",
      "body": "<p>I'm working on a C++ project using OpenCL. I'm using the CPU as an OpenCL device with the  <a href=\"http://registrationcenter.intel.com/irc_nas/5193/intel_code_builder_for_opencl_2015_ubuntu_5.0.0.43_x64.tgz\" rel=\"nofollow\">intel OpenCL runtime</a></p>[...]"
    },
```

Now, I want to get only questions which are closed, is this possible ? How ?

(side note: can I also get only questions which are not closed and have 0 close votes ?)

I've asked [this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967852/get-only-closed-questions-from-the-stack-exchange-api-via-questions), but did not get much of a response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using `/questions` method, you should look at the field `closed_date`. It is empty if the question is not currently closed; otherwise it has the timestamp of the closure event. Note that this method will not filter results based on the `closed_date` field; you'd have to do filtering after receiving the data. This is an inefficient use of the API request quota.

It makes more sense to use [/search/advanced](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) for this, with the parameter Closed set to True or False.

Comment: `advanced-search` works, only problem being that I don't get the exact close reason beyond `"closed_reason": "off-topic"`. I guess I could do a second query to `/questions` with the ids of the questions to get the exact close reason. Thanks !

Comment: The advanced search method can return closed-detail, which contains the full text of the off-topic reasons, etc. It's unchecked in the filter by default, trying adding a checkmark there.